# Sum of values in a dict

Tags: python

I want to have sum of values in a dict.
Below is the code which I have written.

```
results = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for main, month, tot in list_data:
    d = results[main]
    d[month] = tot  
    d.setdefault('total', 0)
    d['total'] += tot
result_output = dict(results)
```

Above code gives below ouput:

```
{u'Apple': {'January': 17, 'February': 1, 'total': 19, 'March': 1}, 
 u'Oranges': {'total': 1, 'March': 1}, 
 u'Graphes': {'January': 24, 'February': 1, 'total': 66, 'March': 41}}
```

But I want output like this:

```
{u'Apple': {'January': 17, 'February': 1, 'total': 19, 'March': 1}, 
 u'Oranges': {'total': 1, 'March': 1}, 
 u'Graphes': {'January': 24, 'February': 1, 'total': 66, 'March': 41, 'April': 1}, 
 u'grandtotal': {'January': 41 , 'February': 3, 'March': 43, 'April':1 }}
```

I was just wondering if anyone could help me with this problem I'm having. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: In general, if you could give sample data that would help; even if its only say three items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? (Untested)

```
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import partial

results = defaultdict(partial(defaultdict, int))
for main, month, tot in list_data:
    results[main][month] += tot
    results[main]["total"] += tot
    results[u"grandtotal"][month] += tot
result_output = dict((k, dict(v)) for k, v in results.items())
```

**EDIT**: result_output now has dict values instead of defaultdict values.

Comment: How to do order in this dict, like fruits should come first then grandtotal ?

Comment: @newbe: python `dict`s are unordered dictionaries so you can't change the order of the keys to make 'fruits' come before 'grand_total' with `dict`s.  There are modified dict classes that are ordered dictionaries in new versions of python (e.g., python 2.7/3.1) have `collections.OrderedDict` http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict and there are similar recipes you can install for older versions of python (e.g., `ordereddict.OrderedDict` http://www.xs4all.nl/~anthon/Python/ordereddict/).  But they will be represented a little differently.

Answer (score 1):

You can try that, not tested...

```
gt = collections.defaultdict(int)         # get a new dict
results = collections.defaultdict(dict) 
for main, month, tot in list_data: 
   d = results[main]
   d[month] = tot  
   gt[month]+=tot                         # populate it
   d.setdefault('total', 0)
   d['total'] += tot
 result_output = dict(results)
 results_output['grand_total'] = gt       # save it
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to add a grandtotal.

If you start with a structure like:

```
starting_data = {u'Apple': {'January': 17, 'February': 1, 'total': 19, 'March': 1}, 
                 u'Oranges': {'total': 1, 'March': 1}, 
                 u'Graphes': {'January': 24, 'February': 1, 'total': 66, 'March': 41}}
```

You can do something like

```
grand_total = defaultdict(int) # makes it default to 0
for fruit, fruitdict in starting_data.items():
    for month, total in fruitdict.items():
        grand_total[month] += total
starting_data[u'grand_total'] = dict(grand_total)
```

This has been tested and gives

```
{u'Apple': {'February': 1, 'January': 17, 'March': 1, 'total': 19},
 u'Graphes': {'February': 1, 'January': 24, 'March': 41, 'total': 66},
 u'Oranges': {'March': 1, 'total': 1},
 u'grand_total': {'February': 2, 'January': 41, 'March': 43, 'total': 86}}
```

Obviously you don't need to go through the list again and could aggregate earlier; but I like to test and don't know the format of the input data.

Answer (score 0):

Using collections.Counter:

```
import collections

results = collections.Counter()

a = {u'Apple': {'January': 17, 'February': 1, 'total': 19, 'March': 1},
     u'Oranges': {'total': 1, 'March': 1},
     u'Graphes': {'January': 24, 'February': 1, 'total': 66, 'March': 41}}

for counts in a.values():
     results.update(counts)

print results # Counter({'total': 86, 'March': 43, 'January': 41, 'February': 2})
```